# Enum error: 'enum' : missing tag name

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums

I am trying to compile an application which is showing error in following line:

```
enum class HoleMaskPixelTypeEnum {HOLE, VALID, UNDETERMINED};
```

I haven't uses enum is such way along with class keyword. If I comment the keyword class then following error occur

```
error C2864: 'HolePixelValueWrapper<T>::Value' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class
```

which is in following code:

```
 template <typename T>
struct HolePixelValueWrapper
{
  HolePixelValueWrapper(const T value) : Value(value){}

  operator T()
  {
    return this->Value;
  }

  T Value = 0;//error here.
};
```

No idea to solve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scoped enumerations (`enum class`) and in-class initialisation of member variables are a fairly new language features (introduced in C++11); according to [this table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport), the former needs Visual Studio 11.0 or later, and the latter is not yet supported.

If your compiler doesn't support scoped enumerations, then the only option is to remove `class`. You might consider scoping it inside a class or namespace, if you don't want to cause wider pollution.

If it doesn't support in-class initialisation, then you'll just have to do it the old-fashioned way in the constructor(s). However, there's no point using it here anyway, since the member is initialised by the only constructor. Just remove the `= 0`.

Answer (score 3):

`enum class Blah` is a C++11 feature.  Are you compiling with a C++11 compiler?

Comment: oh no !! I am using MSVC 15.0.30729.1 and no idea how to check its c++11 features. I think it doesn't have thats why causing error.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question about usage of C++11 in `enum class` definition, in code that describes `HolePixelValueWrapper` you are trying to initialize class member `Value` just in the same place where you declare it and it's not possible (not in C++11), only static class member are allowed to be initilaized like that. Remove `= 0` and it will be OK.

If you want to keep initializing `Value` to zero, you can just make your constructor's parameter to have value by default, like that (of course if it's not breaking your design):

`HolePixelValueWrapper(const T value = 0) : Value(value){}`